# Mockito Spy clarification regd

Tags: mockito

I was trying to spy an object with when__thenReturn and doReturn____when.
The definition of using spy object with when__thenReturn and doReturn____when is:-
when__thenReturn:- Calls the real method, but provides the value mentioned in the stub.
doReturn____when:- Doesn't make a real method call at all. Just provides the value mentioned in the stub.

I have written a small code to test the above one and I couldn't see its not working as expected.

```
public class WeatherService {

  @Autowired
  WeatherDao weatherDao;

  public String testMethod() {
    String response = weatherDao.testDAOMethod();
  }
}

public class WeatherDao {

  public String testDAOMethod() {
    System.out.println("Inside DAO");

    return "Inside DAO test method";
  }
}
```

Now the JUnit code is as follows:-

```
public class WeatherServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  WeatherService weatherService;

  @Spy
  WeatherDao weatherDao;

  @BeforeEach
  public void init() {
    when(weatherDao.testDAOMethod()).thenReturn("Called DAO");
//  doReturn("Called DAO").when(weatherDao).testDAOMethod();
  }

  @Test
  public void testServiceMethod() {
    String response = weatherService.testMethod();
  }
}
```

If I try to run the above test with whenReturn and doReturn, I do see at both cases, sysout statement in DAO is printed. But as per the definition, for doReturn, It doesn't executes the actual method itself. Not sure, why its getting printed for doReturn case.

Second question:- In both the cases, the stub which I have provided is not returned by the DAO method, Its returning only "Inside DAO test method" instead of "Called DAO".

Could someone please help to identify what's the issue over here.

Comment: You are mixing Mockito annotations and Spring Boot annotations, that won't work. And you are not running your test as a Spring Boot nor a Mockito test, so `@Autowired` has no effect and `@Spy` hasn't any effect either. Please [edit] your question to include a complete [mre] (including the test annotations)